# nuxt 3 immediate redirection while an API call is in process doesn't work

Tags: fetch, nuxt3

In my Nuxt 3 app, I have a form on my home page, https://beta.tripheist.com as soon as I make a search from the form, and I go to https://beta.tripheist.com/hotel-search page, and if I click on logo, which is a `<NuxtLink to="/"><img /></NuxtLink>` tag to `/` route, I automatically redirected back to hotel-search page,

**searching criteria**

select location of **Dubai**

select **check in and checkout dates** of something around for example 1 to 3 of May which is next month

leave rest of the options as it is

**as soon as it goes to hotel-search page, please click the logo at the top**

I have searched each and every part of my code, but I don't see a place from where something if defined link this weird redirection

I am using `$fetch` which is a wrapper around https://github.com/unjs/ofetch and it is not an SSR app, the API call goes in `onMounted` hook.

Here are the code snippets from my app

**hotel-search.vue**

```
onMounted(async () => {
  EventBus.off('*')
  sleep(1)
  EventBus.emit("showLoading", {});
  if(search.value.dck || search.value.sid) {
    if(search.value.sid) delete search.value['sid']
    if(search.value.dck) delete search.value['dck']
    query.value = await api.makeQueryString(search.value);
    search.value = api.decodeQueryString(query.value)
    await router.push(`/hotel-search?${query.value}`);
  } 
  await getDataForward();
});
```

**getDataForward** function from the same page

```
const getDataForward = async () => {
  const signal = abortController.signal;
  let pageLang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
  if (pageLang == "iw") {
    pageLang = "ar";
  }
  const search = filterAdd.value;
  search.lang = pageLang;
  const obj = {
    sid: sid.value,
    dck: dck.value,
    language: pageLang,
    records_processed: recordProcessed.value,
    search: search,
  };

  if(initialRequestHappened.value == false) EventBus.emit("showLoading", {});
  const fetchData = await api
    .fetchWithDollerFetch(url.value, JSON.stringify(obj), signal)
    .then((r) => {
      return r;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    });
  if (fetchData !== "undefined" && fetchData?.status == 200) {
    apiCalling.value++
    if (!initialRequestHappened.value) {
      recordProcessed.value = fetchData.data.record_processed;
      totalCount.value = fetchData.data.total_count;
      sid.value = fetchData.data.sid;
      dck.value = fetchData.data.dck;
      thMarkup.value = fetchData.data.th_makrup;
      initialRequestHappened.value = true;
      await addSidAndDckToURL()
      await sendParallelGetDataRequests()
    }
  }
};
```

and **fetchWithDollerFetch** function from my API file

```
async function fetchWithDollerFetch(url, requestBody, signal, token = false) {
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
    };
    if (token == true) {
      headers['Authorization'] = ` Bearer ${session.getToken()}`
    }
    return await $fetch(url, {
      headers: headers,
      signal: signal,
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      method: 'POST',
      body: requestBody,
      retry: 3
    })
  }
```

Thanks in advance, Please do respond as per your understanding and knowledge, as I am stuck with this since 3 days

Comment: Can anybody answer this?

Comment: Not sure but try to remove `await` from hotel-search.vue
`await router.push(...);`

Comment: @fakie I am not redirecting it Via `router.push(...)` instead it is from a `NuxtLink`

Comment: Yes, but you have put router.push inside onMounted hook so it triggers automaticly every time you open this page. Just try to remove it